# Topological properties of subspace topology are the same in larger topological space that contains it?

Tags: general-topology

I was originally interested in the statement: suppose $Y$ is a topological space and consider a fixed subset $X\subseteq Y$. If $X$ is compact in its subspace topology, then it is compact as a subset of $Y$.

**Proof** Let $X\subseteq \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$ be an open cover where $U_\alpha$ is open in $Y$. Taking the intersection with $X$ both sides:
$$X=X\cap X\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha\cap X).$$
Since $X$ is compact in its subspace topology, there exists a finite subcover that
$$X\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^m(U_i\cap X)\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m U_i.$$
That is, $X$ is compact as a subset of $Y$.

Assuming that the above proof is correct, this made me wonder about the more general situation.

**Problem** Suppose $Y$ is a topological space and consider a fixed subset $X\subseteq Y$. If $X$ satisfies some topological property in its subspace topology, then $X$ satisfies the same topological property as a subset of $Y$.

**Question** Is the above statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what topological property you are considering. Let $Y$ be a finite nonempty set and $y_0\in Y$. The open sets of $Y$ are the empty set and each subset which contains $y_0$. Then $X=Y\setminus\{y_0\}$ is discrete and in particular normal Hausdorff, but it is not even $T_0$ in $Y$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is my proof about the compactness statement correct though? Is there a list/characterization of some sort which topological properties are preserved then?

Comment: It's more common to see a list of properties which subspaces inherit. i.e. a subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, a closed subspace of a normal space is normal, etc... The other direction is a little more difficult to make useful statements about (although your proof of the compactness claim is correct).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I did see such statements, but it just so happened that I was interested in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is in general not true, and I will show below that the topological property of being closed (as in $X$ is always closed in $X$ under its subspace topology) can break (in the sense that $X$ need not be a closed subset of $Y$).

Let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ under the usual Archimedean topology and let $X = [0,1) \subseteq Y$. Then $X$ is a closed subset of itself $X$ in the subspace topology (as $X$ is closed in itself) but $X$ is not closed in $Y$ (it does not contain the limit point $x = 1$).

Comment: Ah, okay. Is my proof about the compactness statement correct though?